# MySQL upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0 fails on Failed at step EXEC spawning mysql-systemd-start

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to update MySQL 5.7.21 to MySQL 8.0 using the following commands

```
wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But the installation step results in an error that says

```
systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
systemd[15390]: mysql.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
systemd[15399]: mysql.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
systemd[15424]: mysql.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

I am really not sure where I can find this file `mysql-systemd-start` as when I look in `/usr/share/mysql/` the directory doesn't exist!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps to fix:

1. `vim /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service`  and delete `ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre`  and  `ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post`
2. reboot

Answer (score 1):

While @Роман В's answer is technically correct, the proper way to do this is to use `systemd`'s ability to override unit files instead of modifying system files which will most likely be overwritten when the package upgrades.

1. Use `systemctl edit mysql.service`
2. A blank text editor will spawn
3. Add the following:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=
ExecStartPost=
```

4. Save & Exit

You can verify the edit with `systemctl cat mysql.service`:

BEFORE the edit:

```
# systemctl cat mysql.service
# /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
# MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=on-failure
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755

LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

AFTER the edit (override):

```
# systemctl cat mysql.service
# /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
# MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=on-failure
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755

LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity


# /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPre=
ExecStartPost=
```

Notice the presence of the `override.conf` with the content I added.

After this, you can safely do `dpkg --reconfigure -a` for the upgrade process to complete.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Tried your suggestion, but nothing changed.